# Running a background job in a controller

Tags: plugin-development, queue

I am trying to run a background job in a controller but wondering if its actually possible. I'm not sure about [namespacing](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/queue-jobs.html#adding-your-job-to-the-queue) and could do with some guidance on whether the job should be running in the plugins service or not. I get errors like: Class 'modules\importGeoJson\BaseJob' not found. I cant really tell from docs or find a clear example on this.

```
namespace 
namespace\pluginname\controllers;
use Craft;
use craft\web\Controller;
use craft\web\View;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use craft\db\Query;
use craft\base\Element;
use craft\db\QueryAbortedException;

use craft\helpers\App;

class DefaultController extends Controller{
   //etc
  public function StartJob{
        \craft\helpers\Queue::push(new importGeoJson(), 10);
  }
}

namespace modules\jobs;

class importGeoJson extends BaseJob
{
  public function execute($queue)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Class 'modules\importGeoJson\BaseJob' not found

You're getting this error because you're trying to extend the [craft\queue\BaseJob](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-queue-basejob.html), but you're not importing (aliasing) that class. In general, a simple class identifier will be assumed to belong to the current namespace. So since your class is namespaced to `modules\jobs`, the `BaseJob` class identifier resolves to `modules\jobs\BaseJob`, which doesn't exist, so you get an error.

To fix this, either import the class with a `use` statement or use a fully-qualified class name:

```php
// option 1: import
use craft\queue\BaseJob

class ImportGeoJson extends BaseJob {}
```

```php
// option 2: fully-qualified class name
class ImportGeoJson extends \craft\queue\BaseJob
```

If you use a fully qualified class name, including the leading backslash (`\`)  is important – without it, the class name becomes relative to the current namespace again!

---

Not sure if you're just simplifying for your example code, but you should definitely avoid putting more than one class in one file, and especially avoid multiple namespaces in a single file. Your module will soon grow unwieldy and hard to maintain. Take a look at [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), which provides a good structure to map class names to folders and files. For example, I would use the namespace `modules\jobs\queue` for your `ImportGeoJson` job, which means you can place it in the file `modules\jobs\queue\ImportGeoJson.php`.

Comment: Thanks - PHP oop is into my strong point but avoiding two classes and splitting into services and job seems the way forward. Im using in a plugin as opposed to module as I want the job fired from admin action. Have the task firing now so just gotta figure out the actual work of the job!

Comment: @joomkit If your issue is solved now, would you mind marking my answer as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone strugglng with this. I split the process into a service and a job.

It seems you also have to register your job/services classes in main plugin file first:

```
 $this->setComponents([
            'Importgeojson' => Importgeojson::class, // job
            'MapitapiService' => MapitapiService::class // service
        ]);
```

then call the service from your plugin controller like:

```
    Mapitapi::$plugin->mapitapiService->doBackGroundJob();
```

then in your service method (doBackGroundJob) start the queue job

```
$queue = Craft::$app->getQueue();
$jobId = $queue->push(new Importgeojson());
```

and in your job file (eg as above - 'Importgeojson'), you have you job class with same name were you do the work of the job:

```
class Importgeojson extends BaseJob
{
    // Public Properties
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $someAttribute = 'Some Default';

    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute($queue)
    {
        // Do work here
    }

    // Protected Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function defaultDescription(): string
    {
        return Craft::t('mapitapi', 'Importgeojson');
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set register the job as a component, since you're instantiating it manually anyway. Just make sure to namespace the class correctly and put it in the right place, it should work fine then!